# Query where sum of specified columns (all ints) in row are less than a specified int

Tags: php, mysql, sql, myisam

I'm writing a word search program.

My database is set up to MyISAM
with one table (Words) structured

```
WordID | String | A | B | ... | Z |
------------------------------------
int     varchar int  int ...  int
```

Where the values for columns A - Z are the # of occurrences of that letter in the string.

To write a query to find all possible words made out of a specified (but dynamic - user chosen) set of characters (including wild characters) ie: `"Bu!!er"` should return but, butt, bull, etc

Where

```
 S is the set of characters specified that we can use
 W is the set of characters in a word
```

I'll need to query the database for all strings where

```
 # of occurences in the word for each specified character (not including "!") is less than number of occurrences of that character in the specified string
W_k < S_k where k is each character specified
```

**AND**

```
# of occurrences of letters not specified in the specified string are in SUM less than the total occurrences of the wildcard character ("!") in the specified string 
W_q < S_! where q is each character not specified and S_! total amount of occurrences of "!".
```

For the first part of the `WHERE` statement (W_k < S_k)
For `bu!!er` the statement would be

```
 `B` <= 1 AND `U` <= 1 AND `E` <= 1 AND `R` <= 1
```

And for the second part

```
 `A` + `C` + `D` + ... + `Z` <= 2
```

The complete Where part of the query becomes

```
  ( ( `A` + (IF(`B`-1 < 0, 0, `B`-1)) + `C` + `D` + (IF(`E`-1 < 0, 0, `E`-1)) + `F` + `G` + `H` + `I` + `J` + `K` + `L` + `M` + `N` + `O` + `P` + `Q` + (IF(`R`-1 < 0, 0, `R`-1)) + `S` + `T` + (IF(`U`-1 < 0, 0, `U`-1)) + `V` + `W` + `X` + `Y` + `Z` ) <= 2 )
```

*Is there a better way to do it than this?*

Comment: Yes. Assuming a database is even the proper solution, see normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: What other solution would there be? Looking into normalization now. Thank you.

Comment: Well, a search for scrabble algorithms might offer up some other ideas.

Comment: `IF(B-1 < 0, 0, B-1)` --> `GREATEST(B, 0)`

Comment: You mean `GREATEST (B-1, 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 `A` + `C` + `D` + ... + `Z`
```

Use denormalization? Store the full length in a separate column.

```
 `TOTAL` <= 5
```

As a sidenote:

Your schema restricts the possible queries too much - though it's enough for this job. It might be better to keep all words in the memory (one per server instance) and do "full table scans" or "indexed scans" on the words.

Comment: The problem with storing the full length is that in - `A` + `C` + `D` + ... + `Z` - these are the characters not specified by the user, so they change depending on the user's input each time. Why do you say that it restricts the possible queries? Thank you for your time

Comment: It doesn't solve those type of queries, but I think it solves your *original* problem: "To write a query to find all possible words made out of a specified set of characters (including wild characters)". So what I propose would be the second part of the query.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case I see how it would work. I should have been clearer.